# is it possible to store draggable view position in a database in react native?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm currently doing a react-native project of draggable view where users can drag around and save it in a database. is there anyway to do this?

i tried using React-Native Reanimated but when i store the x and y of the view and load them up again, the position changes from the position i dragged it to.

Here's my code

```
const updateDraggable = async (xTrans,yTrans,id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.put(apiheader + '/draggable/edit/' + id,{x:xTrans,y:yTrans});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
const Dragable = props => {
    const translateX = useSharedValue(props.x);
    const translateY = useSharedValue(props.y);
    const isGestureActive = useSharedValue(false);
    const pan = Gesture.Pan()
        .onStart(()=>{
            
            isGestureActive.value = true;
        })   
        .onChange((evt) => {
            translateX.value += evt.changeX;
            translateY.value += evt.changeY;


        })
        .onEnd(()=>{
            isGestureActive.value=false;
            runOnJS(updateDraggable)(translateX.value,translateX.value,props.item._id)
            
            
            
        })
    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        const zIndex = isGestureActive.value ? 1000 : 1;
        return {
            
            zIndex,
            transform: [
                { translateX: translateX.value },
                { translateY: translateY.value },
            ],
        };
    });

    return (
        <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
            <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.root}>
                <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
                    <Animated.View><Table name={props.item} key={props.item._id} /></Animated.View>
                </GestureDetector>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
        </Animated.View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restructuring your JSX. The `GestureHandlerRootView`, as the name suggests, should be at your entry point:

```
export default function App() {
  return <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>{/* content */}</GestureHandlerRootView>;
}
```

I'd recommend taking a look at the examples in [the docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gestures/pan-gesture) from RNGH as they have a great example of a draggable component. In their example the `<Animated.View>` is also inside the `<GestureDetector>` instead of on the outside.

If your are sure your `props.x` and `props.y` are correct, I don't see an issue why it wouldn't work after these changes.

Comment: Thank you it worked out fine now! 
I also found out that i inputted wrong data on updateTable 

Before: 
const pan = Gesture.Pan()
       .......
        .onEnd(() => {
            runOnJS(updateTable)(translateX.value, translateX.value, props.item._id)
After: 
const pan = Gesture.Pan()
       ....
        .onEnd(() => {
            runOnJS(updateTable)(translateX.value, translateY.value, props.item._id)